# Coin Flipping Probability Mass Function & Expectation

Tags: probability, expectation

A coin comes up Heads with probability *p* and Tails with probability 1-*p*. Flipping this coin four times the sequence of outcomes is noted and then rewritten by replacing Heads with 0s and Tails with 1s. This way, a sequence of length four that consists of 0s and 1s is obtained.

Let X be the number that has this sequence as its base 2 expansion. Example: if the flips are H, T, T, H then the 0-1 sequence is 0110 and X = 0x8 + 1x4 + 1x2 + 0x1 = 6. Plot the probability mass function of X and determine its expectation E(X) in case:

1) p = $\frac{1}{2}$ i.e. the coin is fair

2) p = $\frac{1}{3}$ i.e. the coin is biased

PROGRESS:

Honestly I have made none because I do not know how to generate the probability mass function and getting a bit confused by the "base 2 expansion" bit. Once I have the mass function I think I can calculate the expectation from there. Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are 16 possible ways to flip the coin four times. Each of these 16 ways generates a unique base-2 number. You need to find the probability associated with each of these outcomes. Do you know about binomial probability?

Comment: No I don't unfortunately, does this mean I will need to write out each of the 16 combinations?

It seems I need to do the following:

1. Write out combinations: e.g. 0000,1111,0110 etc
2. Find the value of X for each sequence
3. Find the probability of X for the sequence

Is that correct?

Comment: You could use the combination function to help you, but otherwise, yes, you need to associate each value of $X$ with its probability, so you'll need to calculate each one.

Comment: Ok thanks, am I right in saying for each X value, I multiply the first number in the sequence by 8, second by 4, third by 2, last by 1 for each sequence then sum?

Comment: I don't think so. For example, let's find the probability for $X=6$, which in base-2 is 0110, or two heads and two tails. Assume $p=\frac{1}{2}$ as in case (1). Then $P(X=6)=(1/2)(1/2)(1/2)(1/2)=\frac{1}{16}$. Now assume $p=\frac{1}{3}$ as in case (2). Then $P(X=6)=(1/3)(2/3)(2/3)(1/3)=\frac{4}{81}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is very simple: The order of flips matters.

You are given four random variables $X_i, i = 1,2,3,4$, where each one stands for a toss of a coin, in ascending order of indices. You have to calculate the following quantity : $X = 8X_1 + 4X_2 + 2X_3 + X_4$,right? This can have values between $0$ and $15$.

For the first part: Now, how is $X_i$? Well, it is $0$ or $1$ with probability half, so the expectation value is just $E[X] = 8 \times 0.5  + 4 \times 0.5 + 2 \times 0.5+1 \times 0.5 = 7.5$, because the expectation of one toss is $0 \times 0.5 +1 \times 0.5 = 0.5$.

How about the mass function? Well, each number, from $0$ to $15$, has an equal probability of coming, because each one has a unique representation in binary, and the probability of heads and tails are the same. Hence, it is just $P(i) = \frac{1}{16}$, for $i=0,1, \ldots, 15$ (there are sixteen possibilities in total, each occurs equally probably).

In the second question: The expectation of  each $X_i$ now is $0 \times \frac 13 + 1\times \frac 23 = \frac 23$, so then $E[X] = (8+4+2+1) \times\frac 23 = 10$.

Finally, here, every number has a unique binary expansion, but *this time the heads and tails don't have the same probability*, so the mass function changes, and it changes as follows: given the number of $1$s in the expansion, so many tails are required for the number to come, which happens with higher probability. So more the ones, more the probability.

So, we look at the binary expansions:

1) The numbers having no $1$s is only zero.

2) The numbers having precisely one $1$ are $2$,$4$,$8$,$1$.

3) The numbers having precisely two $1$s are $3$,$5$,$6$,$9$,$10$,$12$.

4) The numbers having precisely three ones are $7$,$11$,$13$,$14$.

5) Only $15$ has four ones.

Hence, we can write down the probabilities as follows:

1) For zero, the probability is $\frac{1}{3^4} = \frac{1}{81}$.

2) For the numbers with only one $1$, the probability is $\frac{1}{3^3} \times \frac{2}{3} = \frac{2}{81}$.

3) For the numbers having $2$ ones, the probability is $\frac{1}{3^2} \times \frac{2^2}{3^2} = \frac{4}{81}$.

4) For the numbers with three $1$s, the probability is $\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{2^3}{3^3} = \frac{8}{81}$.

5) For the numbers with all $1$s, the probability is $\frac{2^4}{3^4} = \frac{16}{81}$.

Hence, this is the probability distribution function in the end:
$$
P(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{81} & x=0 \\
\frac{2}{81} & x=1,2,4,8 \\ 
\frac{4}{81} & x= 3,5,6,9,10,12 \\
\frac{8}{81} & x = 7,11,13,14 \\
\frac{16}{81} & x = 15 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I also used the long way of doing it above and got the exact same answers as you so thank you very much!

Comment: @Fkins You are welcome.Also, your acceptance of my answer has sent my reputation above $10$k (to $10001$), so thank you as well.